# How to merge set of finite maps?

Tags: isabelle

I can merge two finite maps as follows:

```
value "fmadd
  (fmap_of_list [(1::nat,2::nat)])
  (fmap_of_list [(2::nat,3::nat)])"
```

But when I try to merge a set of maps:

```
value "ffold fmadd fmempty {|
  fmap_of_list [(1::nat,2::nat)],
  fmap_of_list [(2::nat,3::nat)]|}"
```

I get the following error:

```
Wellsortedness error:
Type nat ⇀⇩f nat not of sort finite
No type arity fmap :: finite
```

According to definition of `fmap`, it's domain is finite:

```
typedef ('a, 'b) fmap = "{m. finite (dom m)} :: ('a ⇀ 'b) set"
  morphisms fmlookup Abs_fmap
proof
  show "Map.empty ∈ {m. finite (dom m)}"
    by auto
qed
```

But why `fmap` is not finite?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your immediate question:

> But why `fmap` is not finite?

Every `fmap` has a finite domain, but it is not necessarily the case that there are only finitely many values of type `('a, 'b) fmap`. For example, there are infinitely many finitely-sized mappings from `nat` to `nat`.

The problem you're observing is deeper than that: I believe there is no proper code setup for `ffold`. If I try to compute

```
ffold funion fempty {|
  fset_of_list [(1::nat,2::nat)],
  fset_of_list [(2::nat,3::nat)]|}
```

... the error message is similar. For now, I would recommend rewriting it as `fold` on lists:

```
fold fmadd [
  fmap_of_list [(1::nat,2::nat)],
  fmap_of_list [(2::nat,3::nat)]] fmempty
```

It's not the same but it might be useful for your application.