# How to setup code for finite set operations?

Tags: isabelle

The following expression is evaluated fine:

```
value "foldr plus [1::nat, 2] 0"
```

But the following expressions:

```
value "Finite_Set.fold plus 0 (set [1::nat, 2])"
value "ffold plus 0 {|1::nat, 2|}"
```

raise error:

```
Wellsortedness error:
Type nat not of sort finite
No type arity nat :: finite
```

I understand that `nat` is not finite. So `nat set` is not finite too.

But is it possible to define code equations for these functions? I'm trying to prove one. But I'm stuck:

```
lemma finite_set_fold_code [code]:
  "comp_fun_commute f ⟹
   Finite_Set.fold f x (set xs) = foldr f xs x"
  apply (rule Finite_Set.comp_fun_commute.fold_equality)
  apply simp
  apply (induct xs arbitrary: x)
  apply (simp add: Finite_Set.fold_graph.emptyI)
  apply auto
  apply (rule Finite_Set.fold_graph.insertI)
```

**UPDATE:**

The lemma doesn't hold and can't be proven. Duplicates must be removed from a list.

```
interpretation nat_plus_commute: comp_fun_commute "plus :: nat ⇒ nat ⇒ nat"
  by standard auto

lemma finite_set_nat_plus [code]:
  "Finite_Set.fold plus (y :: nat) (set xs) = fold plus (remdups xs) y"
  by (simp add: nat_plus_commute.fold_set_fold_remdups)
```

But I get the following warning:

```
Partially applied constant "Groups.plus_class.plus" on left hand side of equation, in theorem:
Finite_Set.fold op + ?y (set ?xs) ≡ fold op + (remdups ?xs) ?y
```

And still can't evaluate the expression.

**UPDATE 2:**

Actually I can evaluate it using `schematic_goal`:

```
schematic_goal g1:
  "Finite_Set.fold plus 0 (set [1::nat, 2]) = ?x"
  by (simp add: nat_plus_commute.fold_set_fold_remdups)

thm g1
```

What should I do to evaluate it using `value`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to merge set of finite maps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46194813/how-to-merge-set-of-finite-maps)

Comment: Yep, the problem is the same. But I can't manually replace sets by lists in my theory. I need either a function "'a fset => 'a list", or a code equation which translates fold on sets to fold on lists.

Comment: Function "'a fset => 'a list" requires a linear order on a set. So I decided to define a code equation, because it seems easier.